# C# UIAutomation crashes Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, microsoft-ui-automation

we are using .NET-Framework UIAutomation in our WPF application. We want to be notified when user switches to another Microsoft application, e.g. Excel.     Here is our code to register the eventhandler:

*automationFocusChangedEventHandler = OnFocusChange; // eventhandler
Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(automationFocusChangedEventHandler);*

When user runs Excel, edits a formula and uses the mouse to select an option in the list, Excel crashes. See picture:

[image]

We using UIAutomationClient.dll Version 4.7.3062.0

There are some similar posts out there, but no solution!
**Can anybody help? Thanks!**

Comment: Do you have any error messages? Try checking the windows event viewer.

Comment: Does it crash when you remove the handler? Can you put a breakpoint in the handler? Does the eventlog give any details about the crash?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, but I tested it with .Net Framework 4.8 (AnyCPU) (UIAutomationClient.dll v4.0.30319) and Office 2016 (x64). -- Try just `Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChange);`. Also, test the event notification using a different Thread (ThreadPool Thread). Dispatch from `OnFocusChange` to the UI Thread if necessary.

Comment: Also, test FlaUI's [Interop.UIAutomationClient 10.19041.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Interop.UIAutomationClient/)

Comment: Thx for your answers!
When I remove the handler Excel won't crash, of course.

Sometimes, not always I get an error message:

Unknown error:
HResult: 0x80040201
at MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.CheckError(Int32 hr)at 
System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationProperty property, Boolean ignoreDefaultValue)at 
System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.AutomationElementInformation.get_Name()at     ...     <our call to  UIAutomationCore.dll>

Comment: At Windows log I can see this:

Comment: Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: EXCEL.EXE, Version: 16.0.14228.20250, Zeitstempel: 0x610dbf31
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: EXCEL.EXE, Version: 16.0.14228.20250, Zeitstempel: 0x610dbf31
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
Fehleroffset: 0x02302eb8
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x3b74
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d79a5707181bf1
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE